# Question about gamma function recurrence formula.

Tags: gamma-function

I know that $\Gamma(k+1)=k\Gamma(k)$. But I am not sure about $2k\,\Gamma(2k)=$?
Can anyone help me out with this? Is it $\Gamma(2k+1)$ or $\Gamma(2k+2)$?

Comment: Why don't you try some examples, like $k = 2, 3$, to get a sense of what's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove any confusion, $\Gamma(n+1)=n\Gamma(n)$, substitute $n=2k$.